# Laravel relationship implicit caching

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm a little perplexed about the issue I'm having.

As part of my integration test, I'm testing the relationship between two models.

```
public function an_applications_status_is_over_deadline()
{
    //Part 1
    $statusId = factory(ApplicationFlowStatus::class)->create([        // id: 1
        'deadline_hours' => 72
    ])->id;
    $application = factory(Application::class)->create([               // id: 1
        'current_status_id' => $statusId
    ]);
    dump([$application->current_status_id, $application->status()->first()->id, $application->status->id]);

    //Part 2
    $newStatus = factory(ApplicationFlowStatus::class)->create([       // id: 2
        'deadline_hours' => 8
    ]);
    $application->current_status_id = $newStatus->id;
    $application->save();
    dump([$application->current_status_id, $application->status()->first()->id, $application->status->id]);
}
```

On my Application model:

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ApplicationFlowStatus::class, 'current_status_id');
}
```

The first part works flawlessly, however once the send part has executed, the ids gets mixed up and I'm uncertain why.

```
Dump 1:
array:3 [
    0 => 1
    1 => 1
    2 => 1
]

Dump 2:
array:3 [
    0 => 2
    1 => 2
    2 => 1
]
```

Why is the second dump still pointing to first status when `$application->status->id` is used?

I'm wondering is Laravel is caching the relationship behind the scenes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it should handle this situation.

You can use `$application->refresh()` to hopefully solve the problem.

Comment: Yep, that works. Would it make sense to make an issue on their repo about this? :)

Comment: I think you’d need to first find the exact bug, because this use is very common but I’ve not seen this bug before. It’s possibly because you’re not using `id` instead setting your own – but really I don’t really know. If you created a seperate project that just drilled down on this case and submitted it, somebody might be able to work out what’s going on.

Comment: It looks like it's intentional, I made an issue on their repo regardless https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25803